# QGIS Join attributes by field value: fails for Graphical Modeler but Works from Processing Toolbox

Tags: qgis

I am trying to join attributes in an Excel file to a layer in a GeoPackage.

The join works perfectly fine when running the **Join Attributes by Field Value from the Processing Toolbox**. However, when I build a model in the **Graphical Modeler** to do the same join using the same layer and table, I receive an error indicating *"Invalid join attributes"*.

I cannot figure this out:

- First the join works using the tool via the Processing Toolbox. The Graphical Modeler is running the same tool I'm using the same data via the processing toolbox and the graphical modeler
- I've tried converting the polygon and table layers to different formats
- The process works with dummy data that I created
- This suggests to me it's something about one or both layers involved.
- I've checked and all the records for both fields in both datasets are fully populated as INT

What else can I look for to figure out what is causing the tool to fail in Graphical Modeler?

Here's some more information:

1. The QGIS Graphical Model as Python Script:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterString
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFile
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterMapLayer
from qgis.core import QgsExpression
import processing


class PrepCtiData(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString('PackageDate', 'Package Date', multiLine=False, defaultValue=''))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFile('LocationtostoreGeopackage', 'Location to store Geopackage', behavior=QgsProcessingParameterFile.Folder, fileFilter='All files (*.*)', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMapLayer('ISEDCoverage', 'ISED Coverage', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMapLayer('ISEDTableCTIACVShapeToPHHCRTC', 'ISED Table CTI_ACV_ShapeToPHH_CRTC', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMapLayer('ISEDTableCTICPJCRTCqryCTICPJCRTC', 'ISED Table CTI_CPJ_CRTC_qry_CTI_CPJ_CRTC', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMapLayer('ISEDTableCTIMAGCRTCQryCTIMAGCRTC', 'ISED Table CTI_MAG_CRTC_Qry_CTI_MAG_CRTC', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMapLayer('MAGCanada', 'MAG Canada', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMapLayer('PHHCanadawithstringfieldforPHHID', 'PHH Canada (with string field for PHH_ID)', defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(2, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Join ISED_CTI_ACV Coverage to ISED_CTI_CPJ Table
        alg_params = {
            'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': True,
            'FIELD': 'Combined_APP_ID',
            'FIELDS_TO_COPY': [''],
            'FIELD_2': 'Combined_APP_ID',
            'INPUT': parameters['ISEDCoverage'],
            'INPUT_2': parameters['ISEDTableCTICPJCRTCqryCTICPJCRTC'],
            'METHOD': 1,
            'PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['JoinIsed_cti_acvCoverageToIsed_cti_cpjTable'] = processing.run('native:joinattributestable', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Load layer into project
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['JoinIsed_cti_acvCoverageToIsed_cti_cpjTable']['OUTPUT'],
            'NAME': QgsExpression('concat(\'COVERAGE_CTI_\', @PackageDate )').evaluate()
        }
        outputs['LoadLayerIntoProject'] = processing.run('native:loadlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Prep CTI Data'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Prep CTI Data'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return PrepCtiData()
```

2. The same command run through the Processing Toolbox:

```
processing.run("native:joinattributestable",
 {'INPUT':'C:/Users/nganj/Desktop/2022_03_02/CTI_ACV_CRTC.1.2/CTI_ACV_CRTC.TAB',
  'FIELD':'Combined_APP_ID',
  'INPUT_2':'C:/Users/nganj/Desktop/2022_03_02/CTI_ACV_CRTC.1.2/CTI_CPJ_CRTC.xlsx|layername=qry_CTI_CPJ_CRTC',
  'FIELD_2':'Combined APP_ID',
  'FIELDS_TO_COPY':[],
  'METHOD':1,
  'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':False,
  'PREFIX':'',
  'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```